# How to convert milliseconds to a timestamp in C++ with the Arduino IDE?

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide, arduino-c++

I am trying to print data that will be transcribed to a csv file in the Serial Monitor. My attempts to do so result in the milliseconds being tracked decreasing instead of increasing at a preset interval, and consequentially the timestamp decreasing.

```
timestamp,lux
0:0:16,66
0:0:11,30
0:0:7,30
0:0:2,35
1:1:3,30
0:0:59,171
0:0:54,36
0:0:50,35
0:0:45,32
```

I didn't think it was a problem with the timestamp conversion, since my formula seemed to make sense:

```
void writeToCsv() {
  Serial.println("timestamp,lux");
  unsigned timestamp = last_save;
  for (int i = 0; i < EEPROM.length(); i++) {
    int seconds = (int) (timestamp / 1000) % 60;
    int minutes = (int) ((timestamp / (1000*60)) % 60);
    int hours   = (int) ((timestamp / (1000*60*60)) % 24);
    Serial.print(hours);
    Serial.print(":");
    Serial.print(minutes);
    Serial.print(":");
    Serial.print(seconds);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.println(EEPROM.read(i));
    timestamp += LOGGING_DELAY;
  }
  last_save = timestamp;
}
```

Key variables such as `last_save` and `LOGGING_DELAY` are defined earlier in the script. `last_save` is representing the last timestamp at which this method was called. LOGGING_DELAY is the known, preset increment between timestamps used to track the differences. Both were set as the following:

```
#define LOGGING_DELAY 1 * 60 * 60 * 1000
#define HOUR 11 + (23/60) // 11:23 am (the starting time)
int start_time = 1000 * 60 * 60 * HOUR
```

After doing some research, I think the problem may be in the bit-size of the variables containing the milliseconds (since these are very large numbers). If that's so, I'm not sure how to change that (I'm new to C++).

Comment: In Arduino Uno (8-bit MCU), `int` is 16-bit long, it can't hold the value of 1000 * 60 * 60 * HOUR. Use `uint64_t`.

Comment: save problem for the line `unsigned timestamp = last_save;`. It is paramount important to understand the data type that you are dealing with when coding in c++.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use unsigned int for all variables. In your business step it will not be the performance issue. Do not cast it to smaller type without reason. :-)

Comment: But, if `unsigned int` is also 16 bits (as hinted in the comments), this still won't resolve the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say - use bigger integer type (https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/unsignedlong/). Performance here will not be an issue.

Comment: In Arduino - the mills() function returns milliseconds up to max value, and it is more than 42 days. If you project the mobile device - it almost impossible that it will run 42 days without restart. So, I ignore the overflow problem.